# Problem in porting a matplolib backend to matplolib 3 - pyQt5 in a multithread application

Tags: multithreading, qt, matplotlib, backend

I have an application running

- a main thread that is a Qt thread running a QApplication.
- several scripts in other threads.

I want these other scripts to be able to create and manage matplotlib figures and plots using pyplot and a "modified" QtAgg backend (in Qt5). Since any GUI function has to be run in the QApplication, the backend has to "route" any gui code from the script to the qApp. It is a bit complicated to paste here a complete runable code, but here is the architecture used:

The QApplication can receive a signal requesting that a function is run in it.
The signal is emitted by calling an execInGUI(f, *args, **kwargs) function and the f function is run by runGuiCode().

> ```
> from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
>
> class ConnectedQApp(QApplication):
>     runGuiCodeSignal = pyqtSignal('PyQt_PyObject')
>     
>     def __init__(self, args):
>         super().__init__(args)
>         self.runGuiCodeSignal.connect(self._runGuiCode, Qt.QueuedConnection | Qt.UniqueConnection)
>
>     def _runGuiCode(self, funcArgsKwargs):
>         func, args, kwargs = funcArgsKwargs
>         func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> def execInGui(f, *args, **kwargs):
>     qApp = QApplication.instance()
>     qApp.runGuiCodeSignal.emit([f, args, kwargs])
>
> qApp = ConnectedQApp()
> import matplotlib
> matplotlib.use('module://myBackend')
> qApp.exec()
> ```

Now, here is the myBackend adapted from the one I was using in matplotlib 2 Qt4, which does not work any longer in matplotlib 3 Qt5:

> ```
> from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
> import matplotlib
> from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, FigureManagerQT
> from good.path.to.module import execInGui
>
> # seems new_figure_manager() has to be overriden here. But how?
>
> figures = {}  # dict with figure numbers as keys and Qt figure widgets as values
>
> def draw_if_interactive():
>     if not matplotlib.is_interactive():
>         return
>     draw()
>
> def draw():
>     execInGui(drawInGui, matplotlib.pyplot.gcf())
>
> show = draw
>
> def drawInGui(figure):
>     figureNumber = figure.number  
>     if figureNumber not in figures:  
>         widget = FigureManagerQT(FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure), figureNumber)
>         widget.window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, on=False)
>         figures[figureNumber] = widget
>     else:
>         widget = figures[figureNumber]
>     widget.show()  
>     widget.canvas.draw()
> ```

The problem is that when running from another thread

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> fig = plt.figure()
> ```

one  gets infinite recursions on the pyplot.new_figure_manager() method.
myBackend seems to have also to redefine the method new_figure_manager(), which I don't understand. The doc on how to write his own interactive backend for matplotlib is also not super clear. So, I am lost.

My question is: what is the minimum myBackend I need for my purpose?